# How to convert Java Request params into JSON String

Tags: java, json, string, gson

I have a problem with converting values from Java Request into JSON String.
Im looking for good library, which convert my param keys and values into JSON.

So far I've written a class, which turns my map of params  into JSON String. However, as we know, request params keys looks like this:

```
dto.author.name="Davos"&dto.author.age=47&dto.code="045f"
```

My class can convert that request params into JSON String which looks like this:

```
{'author':{'name':'Davos'},'author':{'age':47},'code':'045f'}
```

which is not quite good for Gson object, because 'author' object inside JSON object is beingrepeated for every 'author' request value, so Gson can't handle that and fill only one repeated object value.

My question is, is there any library, which gets Map of paramerers like

```
dto.author.name='Davos'
dto.author.age=47
dto.code='045f'
dto.books=[{'title': 'testTitle'}, {'title': 'secondTitle'}]
```

and can produce JSON String with nested objects based on 'bean' keys? I expect that final output will looks like that ('dto.' key fragment is being removed before execution):

```
{'author':{'name':'Davos','age':47},'code':'045f','books':[{'title': 'testTitle'},{'title': 'secondTitle'}]}
```

Any ideas guys? I'm revlolving aroud JSON-simple library, but for now I can't figure out, how it would handle 'bean' keys and convert it into nested JSON objects.

Comment: All MVC frameworks I've used can transform such request parameters into POJOs, and JSON marshallers can transform POJOs into JSON.

Comment: Yep, but SprngMVC can't handle http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36967491/spring-modelattribute-how-do-i-bind-a-json-array-into-a-java-collection this via @ModelAttribute, so Im trying to build object manually from request.

Comment: Why do you mix form data and JSON? If you can send JSON, why don't you send everything as JSON in the body? That said, you could simply unmarchall the JSON string in dto.books, set the list of books in your POJO, and then marshal the POJO.